# Spark saveAsTextFile is not working as expected, please refer below code

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

```
val reduced_rdd = mofm.reduceByKey(_ + _)
                      .map(item => item.swap)
                      .sortByKey(false)
                      .take(5)
                      .saveAsTextFile("/home/scrapbook/tutorial/IPLData/")
```

gives error:

```
<console>:40: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[(Int, String)]
   val reduced_rdd = mofm.reduceByKey(_ + _).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false).take(5).saveAsTextFile("/home/scrapbook/tutorial/IPLData/")
```

Comment: Here is the result of reduced_rdd -- scala> reduced_rdd.foreach(println)
(17,CH Gayle)
(16,YK Pathan)
(15,AB de Villiers)
(14,DA Warner)
(13,SK Raina)

Answer (score 0):

```
.take(5) or .collect
```

cause the RDD type to be dropped.

saveAsTextFile needs an RDD; you no longer have that after take(5) or collect.

You need to:

```
val x = ...
...
take(5)

sc.parallelize(x).saveAsTextFile("path")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
take(5) is an action on RDD which returns a Array (list).
```

This means there is no saveAsTextFile method to call as Arrays don't have such methods.

That's what the error suggest too -

> saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array

Any action on RDD returns actual dataset (depending on what action is called)

You can read about different action functions in Spark here - [Actions in Spark RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions)

Now if you want to save data in RDD into the text file, you need to call saveAsTextFile("path_to_file") over rdd.